# Updating a value within a file written from a list

Tags: python

I'm currently storing task data in a text file and looking to update a value that indicates if the task is complete. I'm reading the file into a list and will update the value.

What are the options for writing it back to the file? Is it to write a new line for the task at the current index and then remove the previous line? Append the updated task and remove the previous entry, similar to above or is there a way to Update the file entry directly?

Entries in the file look like this, where the No value indicates task completion.

```
admin;Add functionality to task manager;Add additional options and refactor the code.;2022-12-01;2022-11-22;No;1
user1;refactoring code part 1;update the functionality of adding a new user;2024-01-15;2024-01-09;No;2
user1;refactoring code part 2;add task numbers to tasks;2024-01-15;2024-01-09;No;3
```

Comment: Both updating the file at the position of the updated task or appending the updated task to the end of the file and removing the old version are options that could be done. Which one do you want to actually do though? Do you want the updated value to be in the same location in the output file or do you not mind it being at the end?

Comment: "Lines" don't really exist in text files; they're just a series of characters some of which represent line breaks. Generally it's easiest to manipulate the content in memory (e.g. as a list of strings) then overwrite the whole lot.

Comment: I was considering putting it back in at the same location just because i give them a task number, it won't matter if it's written at the end of the file though. I just wondered if these were the only two options for updating the file once i had updated the value via a list or if it was possible to target the value in the file and update.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it would be to create a new string, iterate over the lines (`f.readlines()`) appending the current line to this new string while verifying if the line needs to be updated

Comment: Do you need Python code for this, or are you looking for discussions on approaches only?

Comment: Hi @iihsan, i was interested in what approaches were available, i'm new to Python and aware of Lists, Dictionaries etc and reading from and writing to a file but only to the level of appending to the list or inserting at the index.

Answer (score 0):

For tabular data, you should consider using *pandas* to read the file like so:

```
with open('your_text_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')
```

Then, assuming your file only has three lines like your example above, use indexing to replace the value:

```
data.at[2, 5] = 'Yes' #If you're editing the last line
```

Then use the built-in *to_csv* method to write back out again:

```
data.to_csv('your_new_text_file.txt', sep=';', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was thinking of, will this overwrite the file is using the same file name? Will go and read up on pandas

Comment: If you use the same name for the output file, it will overwrite it, no questions asked (so keep that in mind). :)